# ld: duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 osx 10.9 but can't find operator

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I'm getting this error message, trying to compile something that runs fine in ubuntu

```
ld: duplicate symbol 
  wns::service::dll::StationTypes::EnumItem<1, wns::NullType>::operator int()in 
  .build/dbg/openwns-library/src/scheduler/metascheduler/MetaScheduler.os and 
  .build/dbg/openwns-library/src/scheduler/metascheduler/IMetaScheduler.os 
for architecture x86_64
```

I can't really figure out what operator this is about.

The source code is available at:
https://gist.github.com/fishman/7488425

Comment: It appears to be a cast-operator and you have it defined in two files. (I had to edit the error message to see the difference in the files, and hopefully you can see them now too.

Comment: i don't see it... sorry. i diff'd the files. can you help me out please?

Comment: I'd look for an operator defined in a header file that is not marked inline.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/7498727